# YouTube Data API search results include videos outside the specified channel

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I specified a certain `channelId` in the YouTube Data API query, but the results include videos from outside that channel:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCVZyJ-yJ60EZyMXLnIs0_OA&maxResults=5&key={{your key}}`

In the results there are items that are not from the channel specified by the parameter `channelId` in the request:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "CqAEn3U3yOet5Dzo4akpnniRK58",
  "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
  "regionCode": "JP",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 8,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "PzY2_uuWT5JXecEOIgv5a4H3RsE",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "820RgL1fc8g"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2019-08-16T10:25:55Z",
        "channelId": "UC9FTt8SigjBd2bzzH3QCCVQ",
        "title": "薬師寺　新管主への継承法要",
        "description": "2019/8/16.",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/820RgL1fc8g/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/820RgL1fc8g/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/820RgL1fc8g/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "奈良テレビチャンネル",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2019-08-16T10:25:55Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "JIDp4JJTHmn1YL3QpbfG7ZkIhWg",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "qwmHF5kvfuk"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2016-07-04T04:19:41Z",
        "channelId": "UCHeX3CiVyozXzcYjLqmkXuQ",
        "title": "落合西光寺双盤念仏～5分ver",
        "description": "製作…平成27年度埼玉県民俗文化財を活かした地域活性化実行委員会30分verはこちら…https://youtu.be/QcJjlwqNRqk.",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/qwmHF5kvfuk/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/qwmHF5kvfuk/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/qwmHF5kvfuk/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Hanno City",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2016-07-04T04:19:41Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "WhRD0hdEdos_8_3sIMnSfKeBOos",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#channel",
        "channelId": "UCVZyJ-yJ60EZyMXLnIs0_OA"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2019-03-15T07:18:32Z",
        "channelId": "UCVZyJ-yJ60EZyMXLnIs0_OA",
        "title": "世田谷デジタルミュージアム",
        "description": "",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwninEQgZmbCwRKlSlpaqXerK3i2pXTX2fw0ctyW5=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwninEQgZmbCwRKlSlpaqXerK3i2pXTX2fw0ctyW5=s240-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwninEQgZmbCwRKlSlpaqXerK3i2pXTX2fw0ctyW5=s800-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "世田谷デジタルミュージアム",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2019-03-15T07:18:32Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "mGoPgXXCpvtW28-eAzPkxjQ-goc",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "DgeWR7q2_V4"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2014-08-22T05:32:22Z",
        "channelId": "UC_kYlv-j7o3j1979t35htzQ",
        "title": "双盤念仏(そうばんねんぶつ) 九品仏浄真寺 閻魔堂 平成26年",
        "description": "東京都世田谷区にある九品仏浄真寺の閻魔堂で行われた双盤念仏(そうばんねんぶつ)です。 平成26年8月16日(土)撮影.",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DgeWR7q2_V4/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DgeWR7q2_V4/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DgeWR7q2_V4/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "ヒコボン/ohiko2000",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2014-08-22T05:32:22Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "f6Uukvz6P_iy8eqLdGrIckIzV6w",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "RPtB3ibF9Mg"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2015-10-15T08:42:50Z",
        "channelId": "UCH2rOy40BxSSfNZwcCuVGzg",
        "title": "平成27年10月13日建長寺僧堂落慶法要",
        "description": "",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RPtB3ibF9Mg/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RPtB3ibF9Mg/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RPtB3ibF9Mg/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "建長寺",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2015-10-15T08:42:50Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I confirm obtaining from the API the exact output shown above. In my opinion this is a bug of [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint and it should be reported as such to Google through its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have reported this issue to Google through its [own issue tracker site](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues).

Comment: Thanks; [here is the link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174343629) to the issue reported.